# Event Sourcing - 'Upgrading' Projectors

Tags: architecture, cqrs, event-sourcing

I've recently started working on a project that uses CQRS/ES as is underlying architecture but I've hit a bit of a snag and I haven't been able to find any solid information on how to solve this particular problem.

Essentially what I would like to be able to do is handle situations where I need to process additional event types at a later point in time for a particular projection, e.g. when a particular view of the system requires data from a different type of event.

Obviously this would require processing the entire steam of events again (or from some checkpoint) but including the additional events in the new projection.

My question is, how do people typically solve this problem? From what I understand it would be a case of starting up a new projection alongside the current projection and then taking down the old projection in place of the new one.

Though this raises a few additional questions:

1. How is it possible to handle that upgrade gracefully, if I'm projecting into a relational model, how would I go about handling the switch over to be as seamless as possible, given that both projections would be using different tables (perhaps even on different databases).
2. Can the old projection be completely disposed of at this point or would it be completely reasonable to keep the configuration of the old projection hanging around in storage somewhere? (I can't think of a reason you would need to create an older projection however)

Any pointers would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

Greg Young's advice is to treat your projection function as immutable once in production.

Meaning if you need a different read model, you just create a new one (from time zero), and when you don't need an old one - you delete it.

Yes, it may take time and additional storage, but it is not that much a problem these days.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in one. Let's split it into 2 separate things:

- About the relational model where to write.
- About dropping the old projections.

The first thing you need to analyze is if you control your readers or not, and if they are deployed momolythically with the whole project or not.

Typically for small projects this will hold true, where you code alone or a few dozen coders. Instead if there are hundreds of coders in your company and you don't know who exactly is reading your projections, then you'd better design a "communication plan" to your teammates to make the old projections obsolete in a scheduled calendar.

Let's assume you are in the complex situation.

### a. Design the new tables

Design new tables for the new projector, for example, if your tables were `Monitors`, `Mouses`, `Keyboards` and `AudioDevices` you may want now to create `Monitors_v2`, `Mouses_v2`, `Keyboards_v2` and `Audiodevices_v2` or whatever meaningful name / clean-coding name it represents for your company (for example `MonitorsWithManufacturerInformation`)

If your Monitors have changed but your Keyboards have not, I'd advice for also making a completely separated set of tables of all the aggregates and related concepts to avoid any interaction with the old thing. If you have `Keyboards_v2` and `Keyboard` with duplicated data nobody will complain. If you force them to be in the same table, you are going to be killed by the interactions.

### b. Code the new projectors

I usually have inside the projector the ability to drop and create its own table or tables. For example all my projectors implement a `resetState()` method forced by a `Projector` interface, whcih tipically it just drops and creates some tables:

```
public function resetState()
{
    $this->dropAndCreateTables();
    $this->resetLastProcessedEventPointer();
}

private function dropAndCreateTables()
{
    $this->dropAndCreateTableFormSubmissions();
    $this->dropAndCreateTableDashboard();
    $this->dropAndCreateTableStateTypes();
}
```

Then add the ability to the projecto to process:

- a single event
- and also all pending events

All pending events will mean read where's the pointer, read all the events from the pointer to the present, and process each of them in order, then update the pointer so subsequent calls to processing all the pending events is *idempotent*.

### c. Deploy and run

Deploy the new code (to pre-production if you have) and run this:

- reset state
- process all events

Even if you don't have a pre-production and you run it in production, this is safe as nobody knows about the existance of the new tables. No consumers are reading from there.

### d. Iterate coding and deploying

Inspect if the projections have the shape you desire. If they don't have the aspect that you'd like, you can safely edit those projectors and re-run them again from zero: Destroy the tables, re-create them and store the projected data (the caches of the current state).

Re-inspect and so on until you get a satisfying result.

### e. Connect to the live stream

Once you did the initial catch-up, make sure your projectors listen to the stream and they update the projections eveytime there's a new event.

It does not matter for this answer if it's write-triggered, clock-triggered or read-triggered and it does not matter if you process the stream event by event or in batches, just ensure that after the initial "reset", the stream gets feeding the caches.

### f. Communicate to the teammates making the readers

Once you have it ready, you can safely communicate the teammates that are in charge of coding the readers that you have already deployed a new cache, in those new relational tables.

### g. Backwards compatibility: yes or no?

Do not remove the old versions unless you can have feedback from *all and each* of your readers that they successfully upgraded to the new versions.

If you doubt (ie: 99.999999999% sure) just do not remove the old versions.

If you are sure (ie: 100.000000% sure) disconnect the projectors for some product cycles (will be minutes or days or weeks depending on your project) and check nobody complains about reading soured data (double-check).

If someone complains: it's very easy, run the old projectors to catch-up with the last events and reconnect them. Wait until the reader says "I updated to v2" and repeat.

If nobody complains, you can drop the database tables (they do *not* need any kind of backup, as they all were created in the past from the sourcing events) and you can also drop the old projectors code to clean your codebase (if you ever need to undertand something about how the old projection was made like this, this is why you have git or similar).

If you have "errors" in the old projected data, no software will save you from friendly talking to all of your teammates communicating they "should" upgrade to the new readers unless they agree to process incorrect data (it might happen the error does not affect a reader, and that code can cope with keeping stuck to the old version).

If you are the only-coder or you work with a small team under say 20 people, it's very easy to control the shutdown. But I'd recommend to stick to this "doubling before dropping" even if you are in a small team.

## So to recap: Concise answers

Your question #1: How is it possible to handle that upgrade gracefully, if I'm projecting into a relational model, how would I go about handling the switch over to be as seamless as possible, given that both projections would be using different tables (perhaps even on different databases).

- Take time to select the clean-code names of your new tables and ensure your new projectors never touch the old output, as the names do not conflict. Iterate until the new cook is ready. When it smells good, serve it to the consumers. It's task of the consumers to make their switching at their own pace.

You question #2: Can the old projection be completely disposed of at this point or would it be completely reasonable to keep the configuration of the old projection hanging around in storage somewhere? (I can't think of a reason you would need to create an older projection however)

- You cannot remove the data nor the code unless you are 100% sure no readers are hanging around. When there are no readers, you can disconnect feeding it for a while to raise last-minute awarenesses (does this word exist?). After a safe time with no complains you can safely remove the data with no backup needed, as it in fact the data was a "function" of the events. You can also safely remove the old-projector's code as long as you are backed by a version control system for your code.

Hope to help!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have all the events in your event store sequentially ordered.

On one hand you have your current view model which is up to date with the event store and keeps projecting the new events.

On the other hand, as you said, you start projecting all the events from the event store onto the new view model.

At some point, both view models will catch-up with the event store so both of them represent the current state of your data. That's the moment when you can point your queries against the new view model (and probably forget about the old one).